# adding quickblox android sdk with httpmime

Tags: java, android, http, quickblox

i have android project which uses `httpmime`  library for uploading images to sever using multipart/form request
and i'm now trying to add `quickblox` but when i try to build my project

```
Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lorg/apache/http/entity/mime/FormBodyPart;
```

i made many research on this problem and i found that quickblox contain httpmime and some people advices to remove httpmime and use classes in quickblox.jar but i couldn't find needed classes in quickblox.jar

for ex :MultipartEntityBuilder and StringBody.

any help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solved my problem by by adding `quickblox` jars files in my project build path then i deleted `httpmime` jar file from my project lib
after that i downloaded the `httpmime 4.3` source jar from here
[http mime source](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/h/Downloadhttpmime43sourcesjar.htm) and extract it
then created an android library project and added the `httpmime` packages to it with changes the packages name from
`org.apache.http.mime`  to  `myname.org,apache.http.mime`
finally i added the project as a library in my project and every things working great without any conflict